# issue on casting in java

Tags: java

I am new to java and I have some problem on Casting.
I have a class called Parent, and a class called Children, the Children class is the subclass of Parent.

```
public class Parent
{
    int age;
    String occupation;

    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println("My age is:"+ age + "and i am a:" + occupation);
    }
}



public class Children extends Parent
{
    int height;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Children c = new Children();
        Parent p = new Parent();

        p=c;
        c=(Children) p;

        /**Here***/



    }

}
```

My problem is, when I add p.XXX after the casting, I only see the age and occupation accessible for instance p. and when I do c.xxx, I see all age, occupation and height accessible.
I thought when I do p=c, p now are considered to be an instance of a children class isn't it? If yes, then why i didnt see the height integer accessible?
And when I do c=(Children)p, an instance of Parent class is assigned to an instance of Children class, and since the Parent instance doesn't have a  option, that why we do a casting from parent to children, correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I thought when I do p=c, p now are considered to be an instance of a children class isn't it?

No. The *type* of the variable `p` is still `Parent`. The *value* will be a reference to an instance of `Children`, but the compiler doesn't take that into account. It only uses the declared type of the variable.

> And when I do `c=(Children)p`, an instance of `Parent` class is assigned to an instance of `Children` class, and since the `Parent` instance doesn't have a option, that why we do a casting from parent to children, correct?

Well you're not changing the *instance* at all. You're casting an expression of type `Parent` - the value will be a reference. At execution time, the JVM will ensure that the value is actually a reference to an instance of `Children` or some subtype (or null) - if it isn't, the JVM will throw an exception.

It's very important to distinguish between variables, references and objects - they're three quite different concepts, and making sure you understand the difference between them will make a lot of other things clearer.

Comment: then what is the use of p=c??

Comment: @qwrqwr: It sets the value of `p` to be the same as the value of `c` (at that point in time). That's all it does.

Comment: casting is simply a runtime operation that checks to see if the casted object can be treated as an object of the requested type.  The object itself is left unchanged.  In your case c=(Child)p will only work if the instance of p is actually an instance of a Child or some subclass.
It's called assignment compatibility and can be checked at runtime (before you do a cast like this) by the "instanceof" operator, or by the Class.isAssignableFrom() method.